# Read GeoJSON data from MongDB in Xcode 8.1 Swift 3?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, geojson

I have a NodeJS API that queries a MongoDB cluster and returns nearby data in the following format.  The issue is I can't enumerate the locations with Swift 3 and XCode 8.1.

[
  {
    "_id": "57b03fa32c6835946afd358c",
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [
        144.2,
        -34
      ],
      "elevation": "1",
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "name": "Resource 01",
    "url": "http://www.url.com/Resource01.html"
  },
  {
    "_id": "34b03fa32c6835946afd358c",
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [
        154.2,
        -35.3
      ],
      "elevation": "1",
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "name": "Resource 02",
    "url": "http://www.url.com/Resource02.html"
  }
]

This is my Query code.

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

print(json)

if let statusesArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]],
    let jsonbranch = statusesArray?[0] as? [String: AnyObject],
    let therecord = jsonbranch["_id"] as? String {
    print ("_id: " + therecord)
}
```

I tried to use SwiftyJSON but it does not work either?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if let jsonBranch = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]],
    let name = jsonBranch?[0]["name"] as? String {
    print ("name: " + name)
}
if let jsonBranch = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]],
    let name = jsonBranch?[1]["name"] as? String {
    print ("name: " + name)
}
```